# How to cleanly handle an expected error in fetch?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, fetch-api

I need to query some data via a `fetch()` call but I am never sure whether the request will be successful, HTTP-wise: while the server is up, the URL may (legitimely) hit a non-existing page.

I would like to cleanly handle the case and my current approach is by raising an exception:

```js
// the URL is just an example, I did not have anything CORS-enabled (and unavailable) handy, thus the no-cors mode
fetch(`https://cdnjs.com/libraries/sdfsdfsfsdfsdfsdfdf`, {
    mode: 'no-cors'
  })
  .then(r => {
    if (!r.ok) {
      console.log("page does not exist")
      throw Error();
    }
    // if the page exists, it will return JSON data
    return r.json();
  })
  .then(r => {
    console.log(r)
    // things with the JSON happen here
  })
  .catch(err => null)
```

I was hoping to just `return` after `Page does not exist`, but the (empty) return would then be caught by the next `then()`.

**Is this the correct way to exit from a `fetch()` when the requested URL is not available?**

Comment: What would you like to do with this data in each case? i.e. what would you like to do with the JSON if you get it and what would you like to do if there's an error?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that looks about right. I would recommend to use functions for your thens.
It makes the fetch more compact and easier to read.

```js
const url = 'some url';
fetch(url)
  .then(handleErrors)
  .then(parseJSON)
  .then(update)
  .catch(displayErrors);
  
function handleErrors(res){
  if(!res.ok){
    throw Error(`${res.status}: Couldn't load URL.`);
  }
  return res;
}

function parseJSON (res){
  return res.json().then(function(parsedData){
    return parsedData.results[0];
  })
}

function update (){
    //do something with the data
}

function displayErrors(err){
  console.log(err);
}
```